# How to open windows on RDP thin client

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, remote-desktop, gvim

We use RDP thin clients in our company. Each have an IP address with a stand alone linux OS on it

I want to open windows(gvim, xterm, ...) after ssh'ing to another remote server. Though I set DISPLAY variable to RDPIP:0, it is showing following error

```
E233: cannot open displayE852: The child process failed to start the GUI
```

is there any way?

Comment: Have you actually checked that the clients run an X11 server with network access enabled? It's not particularly secure so most systems have disabled it.

Comment: @grawity how that can be checked?

Comment: Also, xhost command is not available on RDP, we usually do

`xhost +`

`setenv DISPLAY display`

Comment: Did you try to start X11 server (`startx`)?